# Add an XML fragment to existing XML payload in BPEL process

Tags: xml, soa, bpel

My current payload XML from BPEL looks like,

```
<Parent>
<child1>
<key>K1</key>
<value>V1<value>
</child1>
<child1>
<key>K11</key>
<value>V11<value>
</child1>
<child2>
<key>K2</key>
<value>V2<value>
</child2>
</Parent>
```

I want to add a new fragment of **child1** into the existing XML payload so that the output looks as follows,

```
<Parent>
<child1>
<key>K1</key>
<value>V1<value>
</child1>
<child1>
<key>K11</key>
<value>V11<value>
</child1>
<child1>
<key>K12</key>
<value>V12<value>
</child1>
<child2>
<key>K2</key>
<value>V2<value>
</child2>
</Parent>
```

I googled and found that bpelx:append method can help in inserting the xml fragment.
But I still can't figure out how to first create/store a new fragment in a String/xml data type so that it can be passed to the existing payload.

Any pointers or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with: The XML snippets you posted are not well-formed, since you are using opening tags at various positions where closing tags should be.

Second, the `bpelx:append` function is not part of BPEL, but a proprietary extension from Oracle (which I guess you are using). You can find documentation on this function, as well as others that might be useful to you [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12483_01/integrate.1013/b28981/manipdoc.htm#CIHDGBGA). Third, you do this transformation in an XPath expression in an `assign` activity.

Now, to your actual question:

> I still can't figure out how to first create/store a new fragment in a
>   String/xml data type so that it can be passed to the existing payload.

That largely depends on where you want to get that data from. Is it hard-coded in the process? Or does it come from a message you received?

*Disclaimer: Since I don't have an instance of Oracle SOA Suite installed, I have not tested these code fragments.*

If it is hard-coded, you can just put it in a literal block:

```
<bpel:assign>
    <bpelx:append>
          <from>
               <literal>
                      <child1>....</child1>
               </literal>  
          </from>
          <to variable="variableWithYourPayload"
                query="/your-ns:Parent" />
    </bpelx:append> 
</bpel:assign>
```

If it is comes from a message you received, then you should have stored the message in a variable from which you can read:

```
<bpel:assign>
    <bpelx:append>
          <from variable="inputMessageWithChild1Content" />
          <to variable="consolidatedBillOfMaterialVar"
                query="/your-ns:Parent" />
    </bpelx:append> 
</bpel:assign>
```

You can also always just create a variable of the XML type. However that requires that the XML type is defined somewhere in the WSDL or XSD files you import, which normally should be the case. This should look somehow like this:

```
<variable name = "myVar" type="myNs:child1" />
<!-- more process code -->
<bpel:assign>
          <from>
               <literal>
                      <child1>....</child1>
               </literal>  
          </from>
          <to variable="myVar" />
</bpel:assign>
```

Afterwards, you can use this variable in an `append` just like in the second snippet.

Comment: I tried using literal but it gives compilation error as it doesn't seem to recognize literal. So I used <from expression="the hardcoded xml fragment escaped by &lt; and &gt;"

Comment: Yet another way of expressing this :) I just like the literal variant more, as you don't have to escape things there. By the way, that variant definitly does work in Oracle BPEL (have used it before). Your compilation errors propably were related to something else (I bet on the usual suspect: namespaces).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a compilation error for `<literal>` and realized that I had to use namespace with it. Once I switched it to `<bpel:literal>` I was able to compile and deploy without any issues. Just make sure you are using the correct name space.

```
<variable name = "myVar" type="myNs:child1" /> <!-- more process code
--> <bpelx:assign>
          <from>
               <bpel:literal>
                      <child1>....</child1>
               </bpel:literal>  
          </bpelx:from>
          <to variable="myVar" />
    </bpel:assign>
```